Intuitively, why do flushes overtake straights as the number of cards in hand increases?
A 5-card poker hand is more likely to be a straight than a flush.
But a 13-card bridge hand is more likely to contain a 5-card flush than a 5-card straight (source: I read it online somewhere).
What is the most intuitively convincing explanation for why adding cards causes flushes to overtake straights?
It's clear that flushes must overtake straights by the 17th card since it's impossible to have a 17-card hand without a flush, but I'm more interested in why the first few additional cards benefit flushes more than straights. I'm guessing the answer will involve arguing why straights are more correlated than flushes (meaning you're more likely to have a hand where lots of different 5-card subsets are straights, which must be balanced by it being more likely that you will have a hand where no 5-card subset is a straight).
